# Beamer layout for including webcam zone

Tags: beamer, formatting

I am preparing a beamer presentation that I will show onscreen (most likely full page PDF) while recording myself giving the presentation with a webcam, and that will show me in the bottom right of the screen.

Now the whole presentation and webcam capture thing (including webcam capture placement) is being done with my video package, but what I need is for a clear area in the bottom right that will not fill with text so that I know I can make my presentation without faffing around when it comes to keeping the 'webcam reserved' section clear.

What I imagine I need is an L shaped default area for the text to be written in, but have no idea how to produce this? My attempts so far have been laughably bad.

Has anyone any experience of attempting this who would be willing to share?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Interesting question.

Comment: Not a solution, but maybe a helpful if you end up to manually keep this area free: `\logo{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}` could be used as an indicator which area you want to keep free.

Answer (score 3):

For frames which contain only ordinary text, you could use the `shapepar` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\setlength{\cutoutsep}{2cm} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cutout{r}(-1cm,.75\paperheight)\shapepar{\squareshape}\textcolor{bg}{.}\par
\lipsum*[1-2]
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]